# Substitution in vi

Tags: vi

I have lines in vi of the form

```
any_string($mno,"<anything here>",$log);
run_abc_cmd($mno,"<anything here>",$log);
```

I need to substitute the above lines to

```
any_string($mno,"<anything here>",$log);    
run_abc_cmd($mno,"<anything here>",$log,"",10);
```

Giving something like this

```
:%s/\$log\);/\$log,\"\",10\);/g
```

does not solve my purpose. What I need here is to substitute a specific pattern with another only on those lines that contain a specific pattern(run_abc_cmd in the above case). Can I do this with substitute in vi?

Comment: @collapsar, Why is it "better suited" ? Note that `sed -i '/^run_abc_cmd/s/,$log/&,"",10/' _infile_` modifies the file in place.

Comment: my vi skills are a bit rusty, didn't remember that it comes with a full-fledged regex substitution engine. tom french's answer works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
:%s/^\(\s*run_abc_cmd([^)]*\)/\1,"",10/g
```

To explain a little bit, the regex `\(captures\)` any line starting (`^`) with any number of whitespace characters followed by `run_abc_cmd(` up to the closing bracket. The replacement is `\1`: a reference to the part that has been captured; followed by the extra bits that you wanted adding on.

Answer (score 0):

```
:%s/^run_abc_cmd.*,$log/&,"",10/
```

& is better than \1 because it allows not to use \( and \).

Note that

```
:/^run_abc_cmd/s/,$log/&,"",10/
```

only select the first matching line when used in /bin/vi (but it select all matching lines in /bin/sed and /bin/ed).